# How to rename package name

Tags: python

When I create a package `long_term_streaming_monitor` by `paster`

What should I do if I want to change `long_term_streaming_monitor` to `long_term_monitor`

What files should I change and how ?

Thanks

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys, os

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
README = open(os.path.join(here, 'README.rst')).read()
NEWS = open(os.path.join(here, 'NEWS.txt')).read()


version = '0.3'

install_requires = [
    # List your project dependencies here.
    # For more details, see:
    # http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies
]


setup(name='long_term_streaming_monitor/',
    version=version,
    description="",
    long_description=README + '\n\n' + NEWS,
    classifiers=[
      # Get strings from http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
    ],
    keywords='',
    url='',
    license='',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=install_requires,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts':
            ['long_term_streaming_monitor/=long_term_streaming_monitor:main']
    }
)
```

Package tree view

```
├── [Mar 21 16:03]  HACKING.txt
├── [Mar 21 16:03]  MANIFEST.in
├── [Mar 21 16:03]  NEWS.txt
├── [Mar 21 16:03]  README.rst
├── [Mar 21 16:03]  bootstrap.py
├── [Mar 21 16:03]  buildout.cfg
├── [Mar 27 18:07]  docs
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:56]  Makefile
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:58]  _build
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:56]  _static
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:56]  _templates
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:56]  conf.py
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:55]  html
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:55]  index.rst
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:55]  long_term_streaming_monitor.rst
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:55]  long_term_streaming_monitor.tests.rst
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:56]  make.bat
│   ├── [Mar 25 11:55]  modules.rst
│   └── [Mar 25 11:58]  y.rst
├── [Mar 27 18:13]  setup.py
└── [Mar 27 18:13]  src
    ├── [Mar 27 18:13]  long_term_streaming_monitor
    └── [Mar  6 18:00]  long_term_streaming_monitor_.egg-info
```

Comment: You might as well do: `import some_super_duper_long_name_thingy as something`

Comment: no, that's no i want, the package is wrote by me, I want to rename its name, So I can use `pip install NEW_NAME_PACKAGE`

Answer (score 2):

rename **long_term_streaming_monitor** to **long_term_monitor** in `setup.py`

`setup(name='long_term_streaming_monitor/', ..)`

to

`setup(name='long_term_monitor', ..)`